# iPhone GPS background Tracking and Data Update from Internet

Tags: iphone, background, gps, connection

I got a little question that prevent me to design an Application.
I know that on the iOS 4.0 you can run GPS tracking while the application is in background state but what if I need to send some information to an external server?

Think about I would like to track user location and update the monitor regionChange with some new regions retrieved via the remote update.

Being very short I would like to establish internet connections to update same data while the App is tracking the user location through GPS in background state and over the 600 seconds available to accomplish a simple long time operation.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.
Gabriele.

Comment: I have similar type of problem and also looking for solution